# is there a standard procedure to update svnant.jar, svnkit.jar, svnClientAdapter.jar, and svnjavahl.jar?

Tags: svn, ant

It seems the svnxxx.jar files used by my ant installation's svn task are out of sync with my command line client - ant's svn task fails to update folders checked out using the command line because it finds an unexpected folder layout.

I've found documentation in subclipse on compiling some of these jars, but the whole process would be long and error-prone, probably with dependencies I don't know about.  I imagine this is a common task.  Does anyone know of some end-to-end documentation, or even automation?

Answer (score 1):

I should've read the readme that came with the zip file.